# Pygame Help; mouse.get_pos()

Tags: python, pygame

I was testing things out in pygame. How come this constantly updates the position of my cursor

```
while 1:
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball,pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print pos
    if pygame.event.get(27):
        a = "exit"
```

While this doesn't?

```
while 1:
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball,pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print pos
    if pygame.event.get():
        a = "exit"
```

Comment: `pygame.event.get()` (without any arguments) gets **and removes** events from the queue; as there is nothing else different in the code samples, my guess would be that (although I can't see exactly why) this is interfering with the `pygame.mouse.get_pos` call.

Comment: `pygame.event.get()` returns an array so essentially, you are checking if an array exists by the call `if pygame.event.get()` which will return true and it will exit. All this will happen instantly so essentially it will update the position of the ball once and then stop forever.

Answer (score 2):

it is to do with the way you have written `pygame.event.get()`

```
while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            a = "exit"
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(ball,pos)
    pygame.display.flip()
    print(pos)
    #here you should also include a pygame.time.Clock().tick(60) to set the FPS
```